# Scala : Force the type of some function to use the type of this in a trait

Tags: scala, this, subtype

I am trying to define the following trait in a meaningful way

```
trait Summable {
    def +(that: Summable): Summable
}
```

But I would like the type of that to be the same as the type of this, so if `A` is `Summable` for instance, then we want the `+` to work only if `that` is of the type `A` and not any other `Summable`.

I could not find anyway of doing that in the doc, if someone have any idea or document I could read about that, I would be glad.

Comment: This is a FAQ:  https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type - TL;DR; use a **typeclass**, even better just use `Semigroup` from **cats**.

Comment: Thank you very much, typeclasses are really powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for F bound polymorphism

```scala
trait Summable[A <: Summable[A]] { self: A =>
    def +(that: A): A
}
```

Now, you can creat a concrete implementation like following,

```scala
class IntSummable(val i: Int) extends Summable[IntSummable] {
  override def +(that: IntSummable): IntSummable = new IntSummable(this.i + that.i)
}

val is1 = new IntSummable(5)
val is2 = new IntSummable(10)

val is3 = is1 + is2
```

But something like following will not compile,

```scala
class DoubleInvalidSummable1(val d: Double) extends Summable[DoubleInvalidSummable1] {
  override def +(that: IntSummable): DoubleInvalidSummable1 = new DoubleInvalidSummable1(this.d + that.i)
}
```

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know about this.